# Powerpoint: Change default placeholder internal margin

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am creating layouts in the Master View.

All placeholders inserted have 0.25cm (left and right) and 0.13cm (top and bottom) internal margins. The text starts 0.25cm from the left border of the placeholder.

Is there a way to set this default margin to be 0?

Edit: The Save as Default Text box method doesn't work here as this option is not available for placeholders.

[inserting placeholders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlCZ3.png)

[powerpoint default placeholder margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izGjs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the text box and choose Format Shape
In the Format Shape pane that opens, click Text Options
Click the Text Box icon (rightmost of the three that appear)
Set Left/Right Top/Bottom margins as desired.

If you want this same treatment for all new text boxes, it should work to right click the text and choose Set As Default Text.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the answer. This works with text boxes, but placeholders don't have this Set as Default option. You can access placeholders by going to View > Slide Master >Insert Placeholder. Right click on a placeholder is this menu: https://i.imgur.com/bjB8Wed.png

Comment: @LjupchoNaumov Good point, but that seems true of CONTENT placeholders (the ones that include icons for charts, text, pictures, etc).  If you add a text placeholder instead, you can set its margins as I described.

Comment: Maybe it's a version issue but I don't have "set as default" on any kind of placeholder. I'm on Powerpoint 2019.

Comment: @LjupchoNaumov Sorry, I didn't make it clear that in the case of text placeholders, you don't need to Set As Default.  Just set the margins the way you want them and they automatically *become* the default when you add a new slide based on the layout with the placeholders.

Comment: I see. Yes that works but my question was on setting it as a default in the Slide Master view. So that if I have 25 placeholders I don't need to set the margins at zero 25 times.

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't offer any help for that other than the formatting paintbrush; it does pick up and apply margin settings along with other formatting. If you want all of the text placeholders formatted identically (font, color etc) you might want to give that a try.

Comment: Amazing, didn't think of the format painter. Works perfectly. Thank you Steve.

Comment: My pleasure @LjupchoNaumov.  I'm sure a bit of VBA could have done the job as well, but sometimes it takes longer to write and use the code that it takes just to do the job manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python script below to set the desired margins in all placeholders. The margins set this way are preserved even when you copy the placeholder to a slide in normal view (default margins are restored when doing this).
Invoking this file on the command line without specifying any parameters will set the margins to zero. If you want a different value of margins, you have to give them in the command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse, os, shutil
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from re import match
from pathlib import Path

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    allow_abbrev=False, 
    description="File name has to be 'todo.pptx' located in the Desktop"
    )

parser.add_argument("-l", "--left", required=False, nargs="?", default=0, type=float, help="left margin")
parser.add_argument("-r", "--right", required=False, nargs="?", default=0, type=float, help="right margin")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--top", required=False, nargs="?", default=0, type=float, help="top margin")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--bottom", required=False, nargs="?", default=0, type=float, help="bottom margin")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

main_path = Path.home() / Path('Desktop')
end_path = main_path / Path('margins')
todo_pptx = main_path / Path('todo.pptx')
todo_zip = main_path / Path('todo.zip')
xml_path = end_path / Path('ppt', 'slideLayouts')
xml_file = end_path / Path('ppt', 'slideLayouts', 'slideLayout2.xml')
custom = main_path / Path('custommargins')
custom_zip = main_path / Path('custommargins.zip')
custom_pptx = main_path / Path('custommargins.pptx')
tag1 = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main}cSld'
tag2 = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main}spTree'
tag3 = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main}sp'
tag4 = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main}txBody'
tag5 = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main}bodyPr'

os.rename(todo_pptx, todo_zip)
shutil.unpack_archive(todo_zip, end_path, 'zip')

def register_all_namespaces(filename):
    namespaces = dict([node for _, node in ET.iterparse(filename, events=['start-ns'])])
    for ns in namespaces:
        ET.register_namespace(ns, namespaces[ns])
register_all_namespaces(xml_file)

for file in os.listdir(xml_path):
    if not file.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = xml_path / Path(file)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    all_bodyPr = root.findall(f'{tag1}/{tag2}/{tag3}/{tag4}/{tag5}')
    
    for elem in all_bodyPr:
        elem.set('lIns', str(args["left"]))
        elem.set('tIns', str(args["top"]))
        elem.set('rIns', str(args["right"]))
        elem.set('bIns', str(args["bottom"]))
    
    tree.write(fullname,
            xml_declaration=True,
            encoding='utf-8',
            method='xml')

shutil.make_archive(custom, 'zip', end_path)
os.rename(custom_zip, custom_pptx)

print('work done!')
```

Comment: This presumed Python is installed, but doesn't say so in the answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124058)